# How to get troublesome r package dependency to load in RStudio?

Tags: r, dependencies, package, rstudio

I am trying to install the `asbio` package in RStudio on a new system. the `mvtnorm` package is a dependency and I cannot get it installed. I cannot get RStudio to see it. Super frustrated -- huge waste of time.

How do I force the `mvtnorm` package to install in RStudio???

I can get it installed in R no problem. I can download the source in the appropriate folder for RStudio no problem. I've tried several `devtools` without any luck.

```r
> install.packages(mvtnorm)
#or
> install_url("http://mvtnorm.R-forge.R-project.org")
```

The error message is either

`Error in install.packages : object 'mvtnorm' not found`

or

`Downloading package from url: http://mvtnorm.R-forge.R-project.org
Error: Don't know how to decompress files with extension org`

Comment: Just to rule out the simplest explanation, have you done `install.packages("mvtnorm")`? Package names in `install.packages` need to be in quotes because they refer to something that doesn't already exist in your R installation, unlike `library`

Comment: @Marius I have tried `install.packages`. Sorry, should have mentioned that too.

Comment: when you are in R studio, in the packages window in the bottom right, if you click `install` does `mvtnorm` come up as an option in there? If not, it is not compatible with your version of R or RStudio. What versions are you running?

Comment: @RAB I'm running RStudio Version 1.2.1335 and R Version 3.5.1. No, it does not come up but there should be a work around.

Comment: there is. go here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm/ scroll to the bottom, download that .tar.gz file, then when you click install in the bottom-right pane select `Install From` and change from CRAN to package archive. Point the location to the recently downloaded file and it will install

Comment: if that doesn't work, I know that version of RStudio will only work with 64bit R, so there's a chance that's causing the issue? maybe go back to the pprevious RStudio version and give it a try there

Comment: @RAB et al., installing from package archive did not work. The `mvtnorm` packaged would load but did not pass inspection and would be subsequently removed. 

What did work: installing the previous version of RStudio (v1.1.463) with R v3.5.1. Of course, other packages (e.g. `OpenBUGS`) are not compatible with this combination but this gets the `asbio` package and all its dependencies functioning. 

Thank you all for the help. Cheers